# Existence of inverse fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, approximation-theory, integral-transforms, approximate-integration

Is it possible to evaluate an inverse fourier transform of these functions?

$f(\omega)=\exp(-(k^2-\omega^2)^{1/2})$,

$g(\omega)=\frac{\exp(-(k^2-\omega^2)^{1/2})}{(k^2-\omega^2)^{1/2}}$,

where k is a constant.

Does the IFT exist for such a function? Are there methods by which one can approximate $f(\omega)$ and $g(\omega)$ using functions which have an inverse fourier transform and thereby obtain an approximate solution in real space?

It would be very helpful if anyone can provide some suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: IFT and Fourier transform are almost the same.  Are there Fourier transforms for your functions?

Comment: Probably not in terms of standard elementary functions. I can get a few handful of terms of a series solution and they involve distributions (delta functions and their derivatives) as well as modified bessel functions of imaginary argument. What is the context for wanting these fourier transforms?

Comment: @kevinkayaks You mean a series solution by use of a Taylor approximation? But that would only be valid around $\omega = \pm k$ for a few terms in the series.
Context: I am inverting the solution obtained from a fourier transformed ODE and the solution is only useful in real space.

Comment: @herbsteinberg You are right. But because of the square root within the exponential I am unable to simplify the integral into one of the gaussian integral forms. I have tried using Mathematica and Maple, but they don't to seem to solve it either.

Comment: I feel it is suspect if it had an inverse, the transform's magnitude fails to decay for large $\omega$. Did you mean $+\omega^2$ (or missed an absolute value inside the sqrt)? I could be mistaken though.

Comment: It may be easier to select the real part before inverting the transform. One challenge of these integrals seems to be the transition to rapid oscillatory behavior at $\omega=k$

Comment: And btw your Taylor series would converge everywhere. If you can expand your exponential and get the resulting integral for arbitrary $n$, you've solved the problem. This is not trivial though, indicating it's unlikely you're going to get a solution in terms of elementary functions if at all